# How to avoid memory leak with abstract class pointers

Tags: c++, class, memory, abstract

Let's assume I got an abstract class ("Book" in the example below) and some derived classes ("ElectroniBook","CodingBook" in the example below). I also want to keep a vector of books in a third class ("Library") and some maps to find them. Let's also assume that I need to create the "Library" from somewhere else using the "addBook" method and then assign it in the main.

Since Book is abstract I eventually need to delete the "Book" pointers I created and I want to do it in some destructor. Neverthless, whenever I try to use delete i got this error message

`Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)`

and if I try to replace raw pointers with shared_pointers or unique_pointers I immediately get errors at compile time telling me I'm trying to use pointers that have already been deleted. Note that I'm using C++ 11.

Here's some code just for example :

```
class Book{
public:
Book(string name, int Npages);
virtual ~Book();
virtual void displayBook() = 0;
private:
string _name;
int _Npages;
}


class ElectronicBook : public Book{
public:
ElectronicBook(string name, int Npages);
~ElectronicBook();
void displayBook() {  //do something 
                    };
}

class CodingBook : public Book{
public:
CodingBook(string name, int Npages);
~CodingBook();
void displayBook() { // do something  else
                    };
}


class Library{
public :
 Library();
~Library(){
 // this doesn't work for me
// for(auto & a : _books)
//    delete a;
//  _books.clear();
// 
//for(int i=0;i<_bookmap.size();++i)
//    delete bookmap.at(i);    
};

void addCodingBook(string name, int Npages){
CodingBook* cb = new CodingBook(name, Npages);
_books.push_back(cb);
_bookmap[name] = cb;

//should I delete anything here?
};

void addEletronicBook(string name, int Npages){
ElectronicBook* eb = new ElectronicBook(name, Npages);
_books.push_back(eb);
_bookmap[name] = eb;

//should I delete anything here?
};

private :
vector<Book*> _books;
map<string, Book*> bookmap;
}


// separeted function
Library createLibrary(){

    Library L;
    while(...){
     //read books from somewhere(file, input or whatever) and 
    // addElectronicBook(...) 
    // addCodingBook(...)
    }

 return L;
}


int main(){

Library myLibrary = createLibrary();
// do something with Library
}
```

Since I did several times "new" to add Books, I need to delete them. I tried to do it in the Library destructor like I showed but I got the error mentioned before.

Comment: Avoid pointers *completely* in your setup. If you want, use a shared_ptr.

Comment: "if I try to replace raw pointers with shared_pointers or unique_pointers I immediately get errors at compile time telling me I'm trying to use pointers that have already been deleted."    one doesn't delete smart pointers - that's somewhat defeating their purpose.   I would suggest you post the code of your attempt to use them since that's the right way to do it but not working for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly your issue, you are freeing twice the same memory:

```
// for(auto & a : _books)
//    delete a;
//  _books.clear();
// 
//for(int i=0;i<_bookmap.size();++i)
//    delete bookmap.at(i);
```

Both `_books` and `bookmap` contain pointers that are pointing to the same ares of memory and you are freeing them twice.
When working with raw pointers you have to decide who is the owner of the memory, say, for example `_books` and who has simply access to the memory but is not responsible for the cleanup. 
So, you should:

1. delete only once, so use only one of the two for loops, say for the sake of argument `_books`
2. make sure that the other non-owning structures, say `bookmap` in our example, never, ever access the memory (i.e. de-reference the pointer) after the deletion

Suggestion: put in the vector `unique_ptr` so the vector is the owner and put raw pointers in the map to signal that the map is not owning. `unique_ptr` will take care of cleaning up the memory for you. If you want to be sure, add some print statements or put break points in the destructors if you have a debugger.

Comment: thanks, your comment helped me for a better understanding. I used a shared_ptr and it worked. With unique ptr it didn't but your help was precious :D

Comment: If you write what is the problem with unique_ptr I can take a look. Let me know.

Comment: Thanks for being this helpful. Here's the dial : if I try to replace ```std::shared_ptr``` with ```std::unique_ptr<Book> eb(new ElectronicBook(...))``` I can't assign eb to my map. Looking up here and there I figured I need to use ```insert``` or ```std::make_unique``` (not available in C++ 11 though). Also, it gives me the error message ```called to deleted constructor ' ...' (aka ... ) note has been explicitly marked deleted here```

Comment: You can't copy a unique_ptr, because, well, it's unique. You can move it though. So you can do _books.push_back(std::move(ptr)) . After this ptr will be pointing to null and the ownership is transferred to the vector

Comment: Ok I'll try, thanks. I'm kind of new with memory problems, I've been taught more recent programming languages in School and I've never cared about memory before. Thanks again!